# Saving source code from HTML textarea to file

Tags: php, html, forms

I am saving C++ code from a textarea of an HTML form using PHP.

The problem is if my code is like below,

```
printf("%d\n");
printf("%d\n");
```

the code that is saved to the file is like this:

```
printf(\"%d\\n\");\nprintf(\"%d\\n\");
```

I want the original code to be saved in the file. If I use,

```
$sourceCode = str_replace('\n',"\n", $sourceCode);
$sourceCode = str_replace('\"',"\"", $sourceCode);
```

the result is like below (saved in the file):

```
printf("%d\
");printf("%d\
");
```

It is clear that replacing `\n` in the source code replaces all the HTML created `\n` along with the `\n` that user gave as input (the original text). The only difference is user's input has an additional `\` before the `\n`, that is `\\n`.

How can I resolve the problem such that only the implicit escape characters will be replaced, but the explicit escape characters, that the user wrote himself, will not be changed?

Comment: What is the PHP you are using to write to a file?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by KenB, we need to see the PHP code that you are using to process the form input.

### Processing Form Input

It looks to me like `addslashes` has been used on the form input.

- If you are doing that in your code, **don't**. This is not the proper way to process form input. Instead, you should use the correct function (such as `htmlspecialchars` or `mysqli_real_escape_string`) to escape the input before you use it. [Read about `addslashes`](http://php.net/function.addslashes.php).
- If you are using an older version of PHP where `magic_quotes_gpc` is on by default, then you should fix that. [Read about 'Disabling Magic Quotes'](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

### Stripping Out the Slashes

If you have no control over the code that is adding the slashes, then you can remove them with a simple PHP function called `stripslashes`.

```
$sourceCode = stripslashes($sourceCode);
```

[Read about `stripslashes`](http://php.net/function.stripslashes.php).

### Understanding Escape Sequences

Your `str_replace` code shows a lack of understanding about escape sequences and/or a lack of understanding about single vs double quotes.

In the following code, a literal `\n` is replaced with a line break. With the double quotes, PHP interprets the `\n` as an escape sequence rather than a literal string.

```
$sourceCode = str_replace('\n',"\n", $sourceCode);
```

What you want is to replace a literal `\\n` with a literal `\n`. Note that to specify a literal backslash it must be doubled; hence the triple backslash you see below.

```
$sourceCode = str_replace('\\\n', '\n', $sourceCode);
```

And although this next line accomplishes what you wanted...

```
$sourceCode = str_replace('\"',"\"", $sourceCode);
```

...it could have been written differently. The following code is easier to read, saves you having to escape the literal `"`, and doesn't require PHP to interpret the string.

```
$sourceCode = str_replace('\"', '"', $sourceCode);
```

I've given the above code as **examples** to explain how PHP interprets escapes sequences, **but don't use them.** Either avoid adding the slashes in the first place or strip them using the proper function, as explained in the first part of this answer.

Read more about [escape sequences](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape.php) and [quoting strings](http://php.net/language.types.string.php).

### The Literal `\n` Between Lines

I'm not sure what you are doing to add the literal `\n` between the lines. We'd need to see your code. But to remove it after the fact, you could try the following

```
$sourceCode = str_replace(';\n', ";\n", $sourceCode);
```

Of course, then you'd likely need to correct other C++ end-of-line sequences. So it is better to not add it in the first place.